# Resize an element of sketch-app symbol without detaching

Tags: sketch-app, resize

I use sketch 51.1 and have a symbol like this:

[image]

I want to resize it in these three ways:

[image]

is it a way to resize a single symbol in three different ways without detaching it? If not, what is the best practice for resolving problems like this?

Comment: You're not really resizing it, but changing the position of the middle segment. I think I might have a solution, I need to test first

Answer (score 0):

First of all correct me if I am wrong but you are stretching the symbol vertically right?

Now another assumption I am making is the fact that the middle line is a separate shape. If not you should make it as a separate shape. 
Considering these assumptions what you can do is

Step 1 : Turn the middle line and the circle at the end into a combined symbol.

Step 2 : Create 2 variants of this symbol - Variant 1 is has fixed height and is pinned to the top & Variant 2 has fixed height and pinned to the bottom.

Now when you stretch the symbol in the instance - in theory, you should get 2 middle lines, one with a fixed distance to the top and the second with a fixed distance to the bottom, just use Overrides to switch off the one you don't want.

Let me know if this solution doesn't work for you - we might be able to work out something else.